# Join array based on another array

Tags: javascript

I am applying `between` condition in filtering of array based on another array. The example below works if array length is 1. If I have more than one, let's say `var expText = ['1-3', '6-9']`. In that case I want `(Value >= lowerValue1 && Value < upperValue1) || (Value >= lowerValue2 && Value < upperValue2)`

```js
var Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5},{"Date":1999,"Value":4},{"Date":2000,"Value":1},{"Date":2001,"Value":3}]
var expText = ['1-3']

expText2 = expText[0].match(/\d+/g);
lowerValue = parseInt(expText2[0]);
upperValue = parseInt(expText2[1]);

result = Annual.filter(function(v) { return (v.Value >= lowerValue && v.Value < upperValue) })

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `filter()`, just loop over your `expText` with `some()` and compare it to each one (meaning move your splitting bit into the loop as well). `some()` will return true if at least one of them match.

Or, to be technical, it will continue until one of them matches, at which point it'll return `true` it runs out of them to check and returns `false`.

```js
const Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5},{"Date":1999,"Value":4},{"Date":2000,"Value":1},{"Date":2001,"Value":3}];
const expTexts = ['1-3', '6-9'];

const result = Annual.filter(function(v) { 
  return expTexts.some(expText => {
    const expText2 = expText.match(/\d+/g);
    const lowerValue = parseInt(expText2[0]);
    const upperValue = parseInt(expText2[1]);

    return (v.Value >= lowerValue && v.Value < upperValue);
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Side note: Obligatory "never, ever, ever use `var`, always use `const` or `let`".

Comment: You can seriously simplify the upper/lower parsing using `split()` and destructuring `const [lowerValue, upperValue] = expText.split('-');`

Comment: Completely agree. I just didn't because it wasn't part of the original question, but I'd definitely do the same in my code. Or even just destructing on the return of match() even.

Comment: That's fair enough

Comment: @samanime Thanks a ton. I am new to JS. can you a bit explain  "never, ever, ever use var, always use const or let"?

Comment: TL;DR, `var` gets hoisted which causes it to end up in a weird scope that causes odd and hard-to-debug bugs. `let` and `const` act how most people would expect (don't get hoisted) and are less error-prone. Use `const` for values that don't change, `let` for values that do. Favor `const` and only switch to `let` when needed. This article seems to be a good longer explanation: https://medium.com/@codingsam/awesome-javascript-no-more-var-working-title-999428999994